# composite graphics white to xor

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I have a panel where I paint an image. 
It is a grayscale image and when I used java 1.7, the code would set itself to interpret white as alpha on the paint and repaint methods like this:

```
g.setXORMode(Color.WHITE);
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), null, null);
```

when i started using java 1.8 tu run it, I got a 
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.java2d.loops.XORComposite cannot be cast to java.awt.AlphaComposite
error message, so as a quick fix, I just disabled XOR.

How do I get the same result now with java 1.8?
Or is there some other way to 'fix' this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I did a quick test using `setXORMode` and worked fine for me using 1.8

Comment: Did you check your imports ?